# TypeOrm Postgres two level nesting

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

`Customer` has 0 or more `OilSeparator`, and `OilSeparator` has 0 or more `Inspection`. How do I fetch a customer with it's OilSeparators that in turn has it's Inspections?

I want to do this:

```
this.customerRepository.findOne({
      where: { id },
      relations: ['oilSeparators, oilSeparators.inspections'],
    });
```

but it's not supported as far as I can see. Do you know how to do this with `createQueryBuilder` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use queryBuilder
example :

```js
this.customerRepository 
      .createQueryBuilder('customer')
      .innerJoinAndSelect('customer.oilSeparators', 'oilSeparators')
      .innerJoin("oilSeparators.inspections", "inspections")
      .getRawOne()
```

or use `eager: true` in inspections Entity

also you can use `.relation(OilSeparator, "customer.OilSeparator.inspections")`

if you need moro information about join [read this](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/relational-query-builder)